# Perfect Graphs, examples of when removing an edge decreases $\omega(\bar{G})$ but not $\chi(\bar{G})$

Tags: graph-theory

**Motivation**: Given graph $G(V,E_1\cup E_2)$, $G_1(V,E_1)$ and $G_2(V,E_2)$ are perfect, I would like to know if G is perfect. Now obviously, this is not true. Take 5 vertices from V, those 5 points can definitely contain a $C_5$, which are partitioned into $E_1$ and $E_2$ so that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are perfect.

Now, before figuring out the above point, I have thought of considering $\bar{G}\subset \bar{G_1}$. However, $\bar{G}$  is not an *induced* subgraph and thus not necessarily perfect! Below is a situation I encountered,

Take a perfect graph $H$ and it's complement $\bar{H}$. Because $H$ is perfect, $\omega(\bar{H})=\chi(\bar{H})$. Removing an edge from $\bar{H}$ might:

1. Have no effect in $\omega(\bar{H})$, and thus no effect on $\chi(\bar{H})$
2. Reduces $\omega(\bar{H})$ by 1, but not $\chi(\bar{H})$
3. Reduces both $\chi(\bar{H})$ and $\omega(\bar{H})$ by 1

**Question**: What is a (preferably simple) example of the 2nd situation? Though this is true, I still would like an example (it helps me learn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is worth noting that a graph $H$ is perfect if and only if $\overline{H}$ is perfect. This statement is known as the [Weak Perfect Graph Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph_theorem) (not to be confused with the [Strong Perfect Graph Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_perfect_graph_theorem)). But this also means that if $H$ is perfect than every induced subgraph of $\overline{H}$ is also perfect. Thus, if we remove an edge including its two ends, then the resulting graph is also perfect (hence, I believe that it does not really matter if we consider a perfect graph $H$ or it's complement $\overline{H}$, since $H$ is the complement of $\overline{H}$ and vice versa anyway).

Therefore, we assume that we remove an edge but keep at least one of its ends (and I suppose that this is what you are asking).

Now, let us consider your second case. Here is an example:

Consider the house graph which looks as follows

[image]

The house graph is a perfect graph and has clique number $\omega=3$ and thus chromatic number $\chi=3$. The complement of the house graph is a $P_5$ and looks as follows.

[image]

For your second case, let us consider $P_5=H$, then $\overline{P_5}=\overline{H}$ is perfect but removing the edge $(2,3) \in E(\overline{H})$ results in a $C_5$ for which $\chi(C_5)=3$ and $\omega(C_5)=2$ as desired.